# How can I display ssh commands executed from another machine?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, networking

Can I see what other users type/execute via SSH in my server via bash or shell?

Comment: Some suggestions: https://serverfault.com/questions/8851/live-view-of-linux-shell-commands-executed-by-another-user

Comment: spying or co-cooperatively?

Answer (score 2):

Read the user history file from their home directory.

```
less .bash_history
```

And if needed then with timestamps too on **history** command.

```
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing their shell, the best bet would be to read their shell's history file in their home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
ssh -l user 10.10.1.1 cat ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: If it's your machine, why would you SSH back to it to look at a local history file?

Comment: @thrig, this uses SSH from another machine to display commands executed.  It's pretty close to the question title.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply type:

```
more ~/.bash_history
```

This will show each and every command that has been executed using an SSH session except the one which you are currently using (if any).

*Note: Tested on Solaris 11.3, Oracle Linux 7.2 and Ubuntu 16.04*

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think this address the question of what *other* users type.

Comment: I tried executing commands on my server using SSH session from another server. It is listing all the commands I executed using that SSH session.

Comment: emphasis on *other* users

Answer (score 0):

Tools are available now that may not have been when the question was asked 2+ years ago. This may not be exactly what OP was asking for either, but it could be valuable for other readers.

You may want to consider [tlog](https://github.com/Scribery/tlog) and the [cockpit-session-recording](https://github.com/Scribery/cockpit-session-recording) package. Red Hat seems to be [promoting these tools with RHEL8](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/getting-started-session-recording-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8-beta).