# How to display commands executed via ssh and their user's IP?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, networking

I asked a question before, but I didn't get a satisfying answer in :
[How can I display ssh commands executed from another machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314308/how-can-i-display-ssh-commands-executed-from-another-machine/353068#353068)

so I'll ask this time precisely.

How to display commands and their users/IP's, executed in my server via SSH.
I'm looking to something like this :

`#tail .bash_history
192.168.1.101 : vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
192.168.1.102 : ls -l
192.168.1.101 : cd .ssh
192.168.1.101 : systemctl reload sshd.service
192.168.1.102 : service --status-all` etc...

Comment: You would need some shell logger to get all of that information. Bash is storing the history, but not the ip addresses.

Comment: rewrite bash to take $SSH_CONNECTION into account when writing .bash_history

Comment: @Jakuje yes, but could change how to write this log. I added a this line `export HISTTIMEFORMAT=$USER@$(hostname -I)"  "` to this file `/etc/bash.bashrc` , it didn't work of course.

Comment: @Archemar `$SSH_CONNECTION` is a variable in the client's host only, not in the server.

Comment: Try this document. It will be helpful for you. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server).

Answer (score 3):

Found the question interesting, so I googled a little, and find [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/559658/log-commands-executed-over-ssh).

More precisely, you need to add this line to your sshd_config.

```
ForceCommand logger -p user.notice "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

According to the `man sshd_config`:

> ForceCommand
> Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand, ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if present. The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c option. This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution. It is most useful inside a Match block. The command originally supplied by the client is available in the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable. Specifying a command of internal-sftp will force the use of an in-process SFTP server that requires no support files when used with ChrootDirectory. The default is none.

On my Debian rsyslog installation user.* is written to `/var/log/user.log`

---

Please note that the above will execute the `logger` command in-place of the original command. If you want to log the command *and* then execute it, you'd have to do something along the lines of (assuming `bash` is available as `/bin/bash`):

```
ForceCommand /bin/bash -rc 'logger -p user.notice "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"; $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND'
```

Or use a wrapper script which is even more restrictive than the restricted shell or - for interactive logins - the `sshrc` (`/etc/ssh/sshrc`) file could be another option to implement the logging.

Comment: I believe this exact command is going to make it impossible to execute the _actual_ command, it will simply log it. You'd need a wrapper script for that. But it's useful nevertheless, so upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server). Edit the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file and add the line

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

at bottom of the file and save it.

Comment: I've submitted an edit because you should use code highlighting to properly submit code snippets. Also, the final single quote seems to be missing.